# collection not add pushing to subarray

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, collections, set

I am using MongoDB and in the past I have been able to use the following to insert or add to a sub array that was already in the DB

Here is my issue, every day we take a look at the itunes top 100 and we insert the songs and artist into our collection, well infact we use two collections to do this job

but the one I am having issue with is the one that we store every single song and artist that has ever appeared in the iTunes top 100.

see code below

```
$collection = static::db()->itunes_collection_australia;
        $document = $collection->findOne(array('song' => (string)$entry->imname, "artist"=>(string)$entry->imartist));


        if (null !== $document) {

            $collection->update(
                array(array('song' => (string)$entry->imname, "artist"=>(string)$entry->imartist)),
                      array('$push' => array("date" => array('$each'=> array((string)$date)),"chartno"=> array('$each'=> array($a))),

            ));

        }
        else
        {
            $collection->insert(array("song"=>(string)$entry->imname, "artist"=>(string)$entry->imartist,"preview"=>(string)$preview,"cd_cover"=>(string)$cover, "price"=>(string)$price,"date"=>array((string)$date),"chartno"=>array($a)));
        }
```

what should be happening is if the artist and song is found to already be the the collection , it should update. at the moment it is not running anything.

and if it is updating its not doing it right.

You see the "date" field should be showing multiple dates same with the chartno it should also be showing what position it was in the charts on that day.

here is how it should look when first inserted.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ea794d6ed348572d000013"),
    "song" : "Timber (feat. Ke$ha)",
    "artist" : "Pitbull",
    "preview" : "http://a1264.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/030/Music6/v4/48/30/3c/48303ca0-c509-8c15-4d4a-7ebd65c74725/mzaf_5507852070192786345.plus.aac.p.m4a",
    "cd_cover" : "http://a1082.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music6/v4/64/41/81/644181ba-d236-211d-809e-057f4352d3d8/886444273480.170x170-75.jpg",
    "price" : "$2.19",
    "date" : [ 
        "2014-01-29T07:10:38-07:00"
    ],
    "chartno" : [ 
        20
    ]
}
```

when the script sees it is back in the top 100 it should add it to the date and chartno fields.

like so

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ea794d6ed348572d000013"),
    "song" : "Timber (feat. Ke$ha)",
    "artist" : "Pitbull",
    "preview" : "http://a1264.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/030/Music6/v4/48/30/3c/48303ca0-c509-8c15-4d4a-7ebd65c74725/mzaf_5507852070192786345.plus.aac.p.m4a",
    "cd_cover" : "http://a1082.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Music6/v4/64/41/81/644181ba-d236-211d-809e-057f4352d3d8/886444273480.170x170-75.jpg",
    "price" : "$2.19",
    "date" : [{
        "2014-01-30T07:10:38-07:00"
    },{2014-01-31T07:10:38-07:00}],
    "chartno" : [ 
        {20},{30}
    ]
}
```

however that is not happening infact nothing seems to be getting added.

I am wondering if I have done something wrong? Well clearly I have.

I have also tried the following `'$addToSet'` but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

your update statement is wrong. you have too many arrays on first parameter. try this:

```
   $collection->update(
        array('song' => (string)$entry->imname, "artist"=>(string)$entry->imartist),
        array('$push' => array("date" => array('$each'=> array((string)$date)),"chartno"=> array('$each'=> array($a))),
    ));
```